# Disable swiping on ion-slides Ionic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

Does anybody know how to disable swiping in the ion-slides? I'm also using VueJS. I've tried the following: `class="slides" [options]="{onlyExternal: false}`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: go to documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#methods

there is a method: `lockSwipes()` to lock swiping.

Comment: Doesn't work for me _vm.lockSwipes is not a function